# Know how many spaces in words

Tags: python, string, list, count

I'm trying to know how many spaces in list for words

```
list = ["Hello       Hello Hello    Hello"]
```

How can I do it?

```
list = ["Hello       Hello Hello    Hello"]

def readSpace():
    print(list.space())
```

I'm trying like this :

thx.

Comment: What would be the expected output for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) method to count the number of occurrences of a character in a string:

```
>>> lst = ["Hello       Hello Hello    Hello", "exa   mple"]
>>> [x.count(" ") for x in lst]
[12, 3]
```

So, you can modify your method to:

```
def count_spaces(lst):
    return [x.count(" ") for x in lst]
```

Note that using `list` as variable name is a poor choice of variable name because it clashes with built-in `list`, and so you should avoid using it.

Comment: You beat me by 9 seconds! :)

Comment: how can I know If there is new line in some list ?

Comment: @mu無 
 
how can I know If there is new line in some list ?

Comment: ok thanks aloooooooot

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension and the [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) string method . Something like:

```
>>> list = ["Hello       Hello Hello    Hello"]
>>> [x.count(" ") for x in list]
 [12]
```